# Chartjs How to render a custom horizon line under X-Axis

Tags: chart.js

I am working ChartJS component using angular2. I would like to know whether there is any way to render as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUlp7.png) or not.

Basically, The Bar Chart rendered on the grid. When I click on the column bar, for example, June the horizontal line should be displayed with the up arrow at the exact month under the column bar. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the `onclick` event of the canvas and check which bar has been clicked with the [`getElementAtEvent`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementatevente) method of chartjs. `getElementAtEvent` gives you all the relevant information you need (chart-width, x-coordinate of the bar, label etc.) to draw a custom line below the chart.

```
    canvas.onclick = function (evt) {
        var activePoints = myBarChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
        if (activePoints[0]) {
            //draw your custom line 
        }
     };
```

The snippet below has two canvas. One for chart.js to draw the actual chart and the second below to draw a line with the text of the clicked label.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    }]
};
var option = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            gridLines: {
                display: true,
                color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            }
        }]
    }
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
    data: data,
    options: option
});

canvas.onclick = function (evt) {
    var activePoints = myBarChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    if (activePoints[0]) {
        var chart = activePoints[0]._chart;
        var canvasX = document.getElementById('xAxis2');
        // set the width of the second canvas to the chart width
        canvasX.width = chart.width;
        var canvas2D = canvasX.getContext('2d');
        // draw the line
        canvas2D.moveTo(0, 20);
        canvas2D.lineTo(activePoints[0]._view.x - 10, 20);
        canvas2D.lineTo(activePoints[0]._view.x, 0);
        canvas2D.lineTo(activePoints[0]._view.x + 10, 20);
        canvas2D.lineTo(canvasX.width, 20);
        canvas2D.stroke();
        // add the label text
        canvas2D.font = '12px serif';
        canvas2D.fillText('for ' + activePoints[0]._view.label, canvasX.width - 100, 15);
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
<canvas id="xAxis2" height="20"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much Shiffty!